# Question not appearing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have seen a double question from the same user: [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27067/how-can-i-test-microprocessor-microcontroller) and [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26925/is-it-feasible-to-test-microprocessor-microcontroller), and reported it.

But looking at the profile of the same, I see only the old question, like if the new one didn't exist. Is that an edit of the other, it's a refresh problem or what?

Answer (score 2):

Those are two different users (see the user IDs in the urls), though with the same display name and gravatar. They are almost certainly the same person, so a moderator will likely merge the accounts which will remove this discrepancy.

Comment: How can that be possible? Are double nicknames allowed?

Comment: Yes, they are allowed. User names are not unique on this site.

Comment: @clabacchio - To be clear, having multiple accounts to upvote your own posts, to circumvent blocks, etc. is not allowed.  Making a duplicate account intentionally to pretend to be someone else is not allowed. However, if someone else named, say, "Fabian" wanted to sign up, they could both use the name.

Comment: @clabacchio If you want to learn more see http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/654/unique-user-names

Comment: @Kellenjb thanks, I've learnt many things about stackexchange and Jeff :)

Answer (score 2):

As [Fabian pointed out,](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/996/857) those are two different users.  One is unregistered, while one is a registered user who also has an account on Stack Oveflow.

It seems that the user attempted to edit their question, but was not logged in.

I've closed question 1 as a dupe and merged it into 2.  I also merged the unregistered user into the registered user.  Now, both questions show up under the remaining user:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/8254/polash?tab=questions